# C++ mass-#include

Tags: c++, include

I always need to write #include "headername.h" when including another class. Is it possible to acess other classes without writing it or including more than 1 class with a "#include"?

Comment: You can include a file that includes other files.

Comment: You could write one wrapper header that includes all the others. But don't be lazy: include what you want, don't include what you don't want.

Comment: @BoBTFish Actually, if you're using precompiled headers, using one giant omnibus include file allows the same pch to used again and again, resulting in faster compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own header file which includes the necessary includes and then include this header file.

Answer (score 1):

What the `#include` directive does is exactly what its name implies, it literally includes the contents of the wanted file into the source. It's done at an early step in the compilation process, before the actual compiler gets the source. The source with all its headers files is called *translation unit*, and it's on this translation unit that the compiler works on.

As for why you need the header files, remember that C++ needs everything to be declared or defined *before* it's being used. If the compiler doesn't know there is a class named `Foo` you can't declare variables of type `Foo`. If you don't `#include` the header file there `Foo` is defined, the compiler simply will not know there is such a class.

If you end up having to include many headers in many source files, you can put the common headers in another header file, whose only purpose is to include other header file. For example, if you in many source file includes `<string>`, `<vector>` and `<iostream>`, then you create a file called `headers.h` containing

```
#ifndef HEADERS_H__
#define HEADERS_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#endif // HEADERS_H__
```

Then you can include this file in your source files instead:

```
#include "headers.h"
```